# Tomcat6 response.sendRedirect() 404 error

Tags: java, jsp, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

I was wondering if anyone has experienced this problem I am having and, if so whether they could provide me with a solution.

I have an 'index.jsp' page which sits outside the WEB-INF folder and consists of the following code:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <%response.sendRedirect("home.htm");%>
   </body>
</html>
```

The page should redirect to 'home.jsp' which sits inside the WEB-INF folder.

The problem i am experiencing is that when I deploy my application in tomcat using Eclipse, the redirect works!

However, when i launch my application in tomcat by running 'startup.sh' from within the tomcat/bin folder I get a 'HTTP Status 404' error.

I am using tomcat 6.0.33

Answer (score 1):

Files in `/WEB-INF` folder are not publicitly accessible. That folder is intented for resources which are not supposed to be accessed directly by the webbrowser, such as JSP include files, JSP files which require a preprocessing (front controller) [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), etcetera.

Your `home.jsp` seem to be just a normal JSP file which is intented to be accessed directly by URL. So, put it *outside* the `/WEB-INF` folder. This way it's just available by http://localhost:8080/context/home.jsp.

As to your concrete requirement, letting `index.jsp` redirect to something else makes really no sense. Just change the `<welcome-file>` setting in `web.xml` to be `home.jsp` instead of `index.jsp`.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This way the `home.jsp` will be opened when the enduser visits http://localhost:8080/context folder directly without specifying any resource file.

Oh, please note that the `.htm` extension is not the same as `.jsp` extension. Fix that accordingly as well, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to 'home.jsp', you have to write 'home.jsp' as sendRedirect parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the initial page to go to is controlled in the web.xml file by the  element.  In stand-alone Tomcat, this defaults to /index.html, then /index.htm, and finally /index.jsp.

It may be that when you start tomcat from within Eclipse, the web plugin does it's own thing with the default web.xml and so the defaults may be slightly different.

Secondly, If you just want index.jsp to redirect to home.htm, you shouldn't wrap the scriptlet with HTML markup tags.  If tomcat decides to flush the output before your scriptlet is executed, the sendRedirect() method will be ignored, as the HTTP headers will have already been written.

Finally, I assume that you have some kind of mapping set up in your web application that handles the 'home.htm' request and forwards to home.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you expecting it to redirect to `home.jsp` when the argument to `sendRedirect` is `home.htm`? Is there a typo? If the file is in fact under `WEB-INF`, it will not be accessible to the browser. Exposing the contents of `WEB-INF` to the world would open up numerous potential security holes. You would need to do the following if you want `home.jsp` to include the contents of `WEB-INF/home.htm`:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/home.htm" />
```